# Use Mootools to select element within iframe content?

Tags: javascript, mootools

Is there a way I can use Mootools selectors to select element(s) within iframe content?

```
$('#myIframe input').addEvent('focus', function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the iFrame is in the same domain and you are using Mootools inside it you can try:

```
$('myIframe').contentDocument.getElements('input').addEvent(
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wn67W/)

Otherwise try this:

```
$('myIframe').contentDocument.querySelector('input').addEventListener(
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LAxhZ/)

---

### Edit:

If you want to catch the `load` event and then add the `focus` listener you could use:

```
var iframe = new IFrame({
    src: '/RN95f/3/show',
    styles: {
        border: '2px solid #ccf'
    },
    events: {
        load: function () {
            alert('The iframe has finished loading.');
            this.contentDocument.getElements('input').addEvent('focus', function () {
                // Do something
                alert('focus on input detected!');
                console.log(this);
            });
        }
    }
});
$(document.body).adopt(iframe);
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/E58VY/)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply Sergio!  This worked for me, but I needed to ensure iframe content was loaded before trying to select my input elements like that.  See my answer below for details.

Comment: Saw the extra info you posted on your answer. Edited my answer with that info, check it out. Didn't understand if you did get it working or not. Anyway, posted a little suggestion of code following the new Iframeconstructor MooTools has.

Comment: I did get it working using the code in my answer below, however, maybe using the IFrame object could be useful.  Ultimately, I think I may want to redesign the site at some point to get away from iframes and use ajax calls instead.  Anyway, thank you for taking time to reply!

Answer (score 1):

Sergio's answer is correct, thank you Sergio for your reply!  However to get that to work, I needed to ensure iframe content was loaded before it would find input elements...

```
$('myIframe').onload = function() {
    $('myIframe').contentDocument.getElements('input').addEvent('focus', function() {
        // Do something
    });
};
```